# how does tfs sync "local" and server versions?

Tags: tfs

I'm using VS 2015 Enterprise and I think TFS 2016.

My boss made some changes on an ssis package and checked them in. I checked the ssis package out and added a Sequence that my boss wanted.  When I tried to check the package in it said there was a conflict with my bosses changes.
So I think I started out with version of the package that was on my local disk, rather than the latest server version.
In my opinion TFS shouldn't let you check something out unless you are working with the latest version.  Is that the case?
I'm not sure I want to use it but is there some high level option that always syncs any checked in server version to your local disk?  Or is the operating rule that you always have to "get latest version" before you start work?

Comment: There's no such thing as TFS 2016. There was 2015, 2017, 2018.